# Alternatives to browser for Java EE applications?

Tags: java, swing, jakarta-ee

My client wants a Java EE application server but doesn't want to access it using a web browser. They don't want to have the "web page" look but rather something like a stand-alone client.

I don't really know how to do it or even what to google.

I was considering defining a Swing client reacting to web services but I don't really know if this is the best way to do it.

I don't want something like RIA.

I guess my question is "how to build a Java EE client outside a web browser?"

Comment: Your client should define this in more detail: "They don't want to have the "web page" look but rather something like a stand-alone client."

Comment: Swing, native mobile application, GWT, applet...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GlassFish allows for having a thick "application client" started with Java WebStart which has easy access to the various things like EJBs inside the server while running on the client.

This might be what your client wants?

http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/entappclient.html

http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2EE/jws-glassfish/part2.html

I've found the Glassfish 3.1 server very easy to work with as a deployment platform on both Windows and Linux.

Answer (score 3):

This is not so unusual.  Define your service interface and expose as `EJB`'s.  Create your client (GUI) via Swing, Eclipse RCP (http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/Rich_Client_Platform), or other RCP technology.  Your client(s), possibly running on multiple workstations, will communicate with centralized services via the EJB client interface.

See http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2EE/appclient/